# Tabs show blank fragment on returning to fragment second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

My project consists of a fragment which has three tabs and when I click on tab each tab opens a new fragment.First time when i open the fragment all three tabs opens their respective fragment fine but then when I go to some other fragment and return back to these fragment then one of the three tabs show blank fragment and sometimes two of three tabs show blank fragment.Then if I return to the main activity and then open these fragments again for first time all three tabs opens their respective fragment fine.Why does this happen?

Comment: @SantoshDhoundiyal posted now..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change

```
 mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(myContext.getSupportFragmentManager());
```

To

```
 mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Comment: error: incompatible types: android.app.FragmentManager cannot be converted to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: change your import android.app.FragmentManager to import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; shows unused import statemnt and same error remains

Comment: remove this line import android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: i never imported that

Comment: change import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
to
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using (Replace your below line to)

```
 mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager(), yourDataList);  //  OR
 mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), yourDataList);
```

You should use (this line)

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), yourDataList);
```